# Magento trigger JS on add to cart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, magento

I'm working on a new shopping sidebar that appears on mouseover etc. While I have all the basic functionality up and working the one thing I am having issues with is the following.

I would like the popup to appear for x seconds (via a js function) once an item has been added to cart and the page reloads.

I'm having greatly difficulty finding where to insert this call to the JS, or the general add to cart success messages.

does anyone have any ideas where it is located?

Thanks

Comment: obvious questions here:  1) what magento version are you using (community, etc); 2.) are you building this as a global sidebar or as a page-specific sidebar (as magento depends on block-level code to create views)?  3.) what code have you written so far?

Comment: i'm using community 1.7, it's a modification of the sidebar block called through the header. as far as showing code goes i thought it a tad bit unnecessary as the code itself works fine, i just can't find where to call my JS function from.

Comment: Are you trying to do something like this http://www.aliceandolivia.com/ona-leather-bustier-gown.html, when a product is added to cart you will see a summary of your cart for a few second?

Answer (score 0):

If this should be shown before the Page is new loaded, you use for example a `onClick` Event on the `addToCart` Elements.

If it should be shown, after the Page is new loaded, you need an observer for the `AddToCart` event, which sets a variable in I think the `Session` and you add a js trigger, if this variable is true (and set it false after this).